# MatPlotLib plot does not have clear boundaries, weird data points

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm attempting to map data, but the map output does not have clear boundaries and the data displayed is not continuous as it should be.
The first map below uses similar data with the exact code as the second map, so I don't know what is going wrong. I was wondering if there was a way to format the code so the plot is similar in style to the first one.
[image: link to png image of plots]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,6))
ax = states_00_14.plot(column='num_fires', cmap='OrRd',
legend=True, ax=ax)
lims = plt.axis('equal')
f.suptitle('US Wildfire count per state in 2000-2014')
ax.set_axis_off()
```

I'm very new to python and matplotlib so I basically have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I'm working in a Jupyter Notebook if that is relevant. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think the second plot is showing points and not polygons.

Comment: The first is a choropleth map, which can be produced by spatial joining (merging) state geometry data with wildfire location data (e.g. https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html) and plotting with geopandas (https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mapping.html). The second map is a scatter plot with circle marker, thus not sharp.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I used GeoPandas for both maps, and I did the spatial join like this: ```states_00_14 = states_00_14.merge(st_cts_00_14.reset_index(name='num_fires'))``` is this not correct?

Comment: That seems to be the case. Is there a way to change data points into polygons with geopandas? I can't find any documentation on that.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the type of the second data frame, pd.dataframe or gpd.dataframe?

Comment: @Kylee - there's no one generic way to turn points into polygons - instead you need to decide how to aggregate the data and find a set of poygons to use for the aggregation. If you have a set of state shapefiles (e.g. downloaded from [US Census Cartographic Boundary Files](//www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html)) you can assign points to the states using [`geopandas.GeoSeries.contains`](//geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.contains.html). You can then group the data by shape and average.

Comment: See e.g. [this question on GIS stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358735/how-to-obtain-mean-maximum-and-mininum-of-all-points-located-within-polygons-u)

Comment: would you be ok with plotly being used for visualisation?

Answer (score 1):

- you didn't define your data sources.  Have used: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/ for state boundaries.  Have used https://data-nifc.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/wfigs-wildland-fire-locations-full-history/explore?showTable=true for source of wild fires
- this means now have to geo data frames, which are simple to complete a spatial join.  This then allows a state to be associated with a point of a fire.

```
# spatial join of fire locations to states
state_fire = gdf_fire.loc[fire_mask, fire_cols].sjoin(
    gdf2.loc[boundary_mask, boundary_cols]
)
```

- once state has been associated, can aggregate data to get number of fires per year per state
- have visualised these first with **plotly** as this allows me to animate frames for each year, plus simpler debugging with hover info
- then visualised with **matplotlib**. recreated same format *GeoDataFrame* you used, aggregating years to 2000-2014, then joined on state polygon for plotting
- added `edgecolor="black"` so that edges are clearly marked.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import requests

# get wild fire data..
# https://data-nifc.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/wfigs-wildland-fire-locations-full-history/explore?showTable=true
gdf_fire = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    requests.get(
        "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/d8fdb82b3931403db3ef47744c825fbf_0.geojson"
    ).json()
)

# fmt: off
# download boundaries
url = "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
# fmt: on

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

# load downloaded boundaries
gdf2 = gpd.read_file(str(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath(f"{f.stem}.shp")))

# a bit of cleanup, data types and CRS
gdf_fire["FireDiscoveryDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(gdf_fire["FireDiscoveryDateTime"])
gdf_fire = gdf_fire.set_crs("EPSG:4326")

# filters, US states and fires with a date...
boundary_cols = ["adm1_code", "iso_3166_2", "iso_a2", "name", "geometry"]
boundary_mask = gdf2["iso_a2"].eq("US")
fire_cols = ["OBJECTID", "FireDiscoveryDateTime", "geometry"]
# fire_mask = gdf_fire["FireDiscoveryDateTime"].dt.year.between(2010,2012)
fire_mask = ~gdf_fire["FireDiscoveryDateTime"].isna()

# spatial join of fire locations to states
state_fire = gdf_fire.loc[fire_mask, fire_cols].sjoin(
    gdf2.loc[boundary_mask, boundary_cols]
)

# summarize data by year and state
df_fires_by_year = (
    state_fire.groupby(
        boundary_cols[0:-1]
        + ["index_right", state_fire["FireDiscoveryDateTime"].dt.year],
        as_index=False,
    )
    .size()
    .sort_values(["FireDiscoveryDateTime", "index_right"])
)

# and finally visualize...
px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df_fires_by_year,
    geojson=gdf2.loc[boundary_mask, "geometry"].__geo_interface__,
    locations="index_right",
    color="size",
    animation_frame="FireDiscoveryDateTime",
    hover_name="name",
    hover_data={"index_right": False},
    color_continuous_scale="OrRd",
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 2,
        "center": {"lat": 39.50, "lon": -98.35},
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
```

[image]

#### matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# recreate dataframe in question.  Exclude Alaska and Hawaii as they mess up boundaries...
# further aggregate the defined years....
states_00_14 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df_fires_by_year.loc[df_fires_by_year["FireDiscoveryDateTime"].between(2000, 2014)]
    .groupby("index_right", as_index=False)
    .agg({"size": "sum"})
    .merge(
        gdf2.loc[boundary_mask & ~gdf2["iso_3166_2"].isin(["US-AK","US-HI"])],
        left_on="index_right",
        right_index=True,
        how="inner",
    )
)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 6))
ax = states_00_14.plot(column="size", cmap="OrRd", legend=True, ax=ax, edgecolor="black")
lims = plt.axis("equal")
f.suptitle("US Wildfire count per state in 2000-2014")
ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]